# UML hypergraphs

Tags: uml

Here's an UML diagram depicting a "hypergraph". It was taught to me that a hypergraph is an n-association.

[image]

However, I'm not sure what relations the diagram implies. Here's my guess:

- a team has n players
- each player has a team
- each team plays during one year
- each year has one team (whatever that means...)
- each person plays during one year
- each year n persons play

Am I correct? If not, *what* did I get wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, it's not always the case that a lack of explicit multiplicity means 1; it is OK in UML to simply omit multiplicity information, especially in the domain model.

Assuming they do intend 1 multiplicities, the best way to read this would probably be "there exist (year, team, player) triples and... 1. for a given team and year, many players are possible; 2. For a given team and player, only one year is possible; 3. For a given year and player, only one team is possible." The only strange one is 2., and even that is plausible as a meaningful business rule. To allow a player to play for the same team in multiple years, make the years multiplicity "many".

Answer (score 0):

The graphical multiplicities in the diagram only express relationships between the three participatns altogether (the three that Patrick has explained in his reply).

There's no information on the one-to-one relationships between the three classes, i.e. the diagram can tell you that a player plays in only one team in a given year but there's no way to know if there's any restriction on the number of teams a player can play during his/her life

Answer (score 0):

I'm quoting a source unknown to me...

**The multiplicity on an association end represents the potential number of values at the end, when the values at the other n-1 ends are fixed (1).**

I.E.

Many Players for (1 Year & 1 Team)

1 Team for (1 Year & 1 Player)

1 Year for (1 Team & 1 Player)

or

(1 Year, 1 Team) => Many Players

(1 Year, 1 Player) => 1 Team

(1 Team, 1 Player) => 1 Year

I visualize rows in an association table where there's a Foreign Key column for each Member in the association. Year, Team and Player.

Each Row is your **hyper-graph** edge. it represents a set of 1 Year, 1 Team & 1 Player. Greater Multiplicities then manifest over multiple rows.

as follows

Many Players for (1 Year & 1 Team):  Maps to Year and Team combinations that aren't unique (many players can have same Year and Team so it means this pair needs to appear for each individual player row)

1 Team for (1 Year & 1 Player): Year, Player unique, at most one row can contain the same combination

1 Year for (1 Team & 1 Player): Team, Player unique